# how to create pom as parent child relation

Tags: java, spring, maven

```
hii i am working on maven i have a situation where i have some layer in my project now i need to layer the poms 
i have top 
Service layer
 >1 presentaion layer
    >> usermanagement

 >2 Application layer
    >> usermanagement

 >3 Business deligatyes
    >> usermanagement

 >4Data Access layer
    >> usermanagement
    >> dataaccessframework

here in this structure i need tu put the dependency of DATAACESSLAYER into BUSINESSDELEGATES and business deligates into application layer and application layer into presentation layer
and all have modules and has relation with parent and child

soo now i need to set the packaging elemnt of these poms

i have set all internal child pom are as JAR
and outer means layer pom as POM
```

but when i am putting the dependancy into another pom of layers it asking for jar
    but when i set layer packaging as jar it has problem in parnt child relation soo please help how to manage this architecture 
    finaly i want a war file from presntation layre

please suggest me ho to do this relation

Comment: please suggest me any solution

Comment: I really don't get what your situation is and what you're trying to achieve. Could you give concrete examples of you pom structure and the problem you face?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a base pom placed in your project directory. This shall also act as the parent pom for all modules for your project. Your project structure should be

```
/project-name
  /pom.xml --> this is the parent pom, include names of all modules here
/project-name/presentation-layer
 /pom.xml --> inside this pom declare its parent 
/project-name/data-access-layer and so on.
```

For packaging have another module in your project that bundles the jars and creates distribution (war etc). Use the [maven-assembly](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) plugin for doing that.

Comment: structure is not wrong i just want to put dependency of three layers into one and another....

Comment: Project build error: 'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging. it cause this error